# fb.gg list of top live streams and/or games

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to receive the public information available on the fb.gg (facebook.com/gaming/) site. Specifically the sorted list of top gaming streams or top games (facebook.com/gaming/?view=directory) based on viewer count.

The closest I found so far was going through each individual game page and looking for the live videos (/v4.0/{page-id}/live_videos), which seems really inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think there is any API for that. And I doubt Facebook would want other sites or apps accessing this info.

Comment: have you ever found API access for this?